# The problem with the Lee's algorithm(Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, interface

This is implementation Lee's algorithm in Java. The problem is the deviation in the backtrace(on screenshots):

[image: how it work and how it should work 1]

[image: how it work and how it should work 2].

Please, any help?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Main {

JFrame frame;
//GENERAL VARIABLES
private int cells = 20;
private int delay = 30;

private int startx = -1;
private int starty = -1;
private int finishx = -1;
private int finishy = -1;
private int tool = 0;
private int checks = 0;
private int length = 0;
private int WIDTH = 850;
private final int HEIGHT = 650;
private final int MSIZE = 600;
private int CSIZE = MSIZE/cells;
//UTIL ARRAYS
private String[] tools = {"Start","Finish","Wall", "Eraser"};
//BOOLEANS
private boolean solving = false;
//UTIL
Node[][] map;
Algorithm Alg = new Algorithm();
Random r = new Random();
//SLIDERS
JSlider size = new JSlider(1,5,4);
JSlider speed = new JSlider(0,500,delay);

//LABELS
JLabel toolL = new JLabel("Toolbox");
JLabel sizeL = new JLabel("Size:");
JLabel cellsL = new JLabel(cells+"x"+cells);
JLabel delayL = new JLabel("Delay:");
JLabel msL = new JLabel(delay+"ms");

JLabel checkL = new JLabel("Checks: "+checks);
JLabel lengthL = new JLabel("Path Length: "+length);
//BUTTONS
JButton searchB = new JButton("Search");
JButton resetB = new JButton("Reset");
JButton clearMapB = new JButton("Clear");
//DROP DOWN
JComboBox toolBx = new JComboBox(tools);
//PANELS
JPanel toolP = new JPanel();
//CANVAS
Map canvas;

public static void main(String[] args) {    //MAIN METHOD
    new Main();
}

public Main() { //CONSTRUCTOR
    clearMap();
    initialize();
}


public void clearMap() {    //CLEAR MAP
    finishx = -1;   //RESET THE START AND FINISH
    finishy = -1;
    startx = -1;
    starty = -1;
    map = new Node[cells][cells];   //CREATE NEW MAP OF NODES
    for(int x = 0; x < cells; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < cells; y++) {
            map[x][y] = new Node(3,x,y);    //SET ALL NODES TO EMPTY
        }
    }
    reset();    //RESET SOME VARIABLES
}

public void resetMap() {    //RESET MAP
    for(int x = 0; x < cells; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < cells; y++) {
            Node current = map[x][y];
            if(current.getType() == 4 || current.getType() == 5)    //CHECK TO SEE IF CURRENT NODE IS EITHER CHECKED OR FINAL PATH
                map[x][y] = new Node(3,x,y);    //RESET IT TO AN EMPTY NODE
        }
    }
    if(startx > -1 && starty > -1) {    //RESET THE START AND FINISH
        map[startx][starty] = new Node(0,startx,starty);
        map[startx][starty].setHops(0);
    }
    if(finishx > -1 && finishy > -1)
        map[finishx][finishy] = new Node(1,finishx,finishy);
    reset();    //RESET SOME VARIABLES
}

private void initialize() { //INITIALIZE THE GUI ELEMENTS
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    frame.setTitle("Lee Algorithm");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    int space = 25;
    int buff = 45;

    toolP.setLayout(null);
    toolP.setBounds(10,10,210,600);

    searchB.setBounds(40,space, 120, 25);
    toolP.add(searchB);
    space+=buff;

    resetB.setBounds(40,space,120,25);
    toolP.add(resetB);
    space+=buff;


    clearMapB.setBounds(40,space, 120, 25);
    toolP.add(clearMapB);
    space+=40;

    toolL.setBounds(40,space,120,25);
    toolP.add(toolL);
    space+=25;

    toolBx.setBounds(40,space,120,25);
    toolP.add(toolBx);
    space+=buff;

    sizeL.setBounds(15,space,40,25);
    toolP.add(sizeL);
    size.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    size.setBounds(50,space,100,25);
    toolP.add(size);
    cellsL.setBounds(160,space,40,25);
    toolP.add(cellsL);
    space+=buff;

    delayL.setBounds(15,space,50,25);
    toolP.add(delayL);
    speed.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    speed.setBounds(50,space,100,25);
    toolP.add(speed);
    msL.setBounds(160,space,40,25);
    toolP.add(msL);
    space+=buff;


    checkL.setBounds(15,space,100,25);
    toolP.add(checkL);
    space+=buff;

    lengthL.setBounds(15,space,100,25);
    toolP.add(lengthL);

    frame.getContentPane().add(toolP);

    canvas = new Map();
    canvas.setBounds(230, 10, MSIZE+1, MSIZE+1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);

    searchB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {        //ACTION LISTENERS
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            reset();
            if((startx > -1 && starty > -1) && (finishx > -1 && finishy > -1))
                solving = true;
        }
    });
    resetB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            resetMap();
            Update();
        }
    });

    clearMapB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            clearMap();
            Update();
        }
    });

    toolBx.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            tool = toolBx.getSelectedIndex();
        }
    });
    size.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            cells = size.getValue()*5;
            clearMap();
            reset();
            Update();
        }
    });
    speed.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            delay = speed.getValue();
            Update();
        }
    });

    startSearch();  //START STATE
}

public void startSearch() { //START STATE
    if(solving)
    {
      Alg.LeeAlg();
    }
    pause();    //PAUSE STATE
}

public void pause() {   //PAUSE STATE
    int i = 0;
    while(!solving) {
        i++;
        if(i > 500)
            i = 0;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    startSearch();  //START STATE
}

public void Update() {  //UPDATE ELEMENTS OF THE GUI

    CSIZE = MSIZE/cells;
    canvas.repaint();
    cellsL.setText(cells+"x"+cells);
    msL.setText(delay+"ms");
    lengthL.setText("Path Length: "+length);

    checkL.setText("Checks: "+checks);
}

public void reset() {   //RESET METHOD
    solving = false;
    length = 0;
    checks = 0;
}

public void delay() {   //DELAY METHOD
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}

class Map extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{ //MAP CLASS

    public Map() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    //REPAINT
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int x = 0; x < cells; x++) {    //PAINT EACH NODE IN THE GRID
            for(int y = 0; y < cells; y++) {
                switch(map[x][y].getType()) {
                    case 0:
                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        break;
                }
                g.fillRect(x*CSIZE,y*CSIZE,CSIZE,CSIZE);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(x*CSIZE,y*CSIZE,CSIZE,CSIZE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            int x = e.getX()/CSIZE;
            int y = e.getY()/CSIZE;
            Node current = map[x][y];
            if((tool == 2 || tool == 3) && (current.getType() != 0 && current.getType() != 1))
                current.setType(tool);
            Update();
        } catch(Exception z) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        resetMap(); //RESET THE MAP WHENEVER CLICKED
        try {
            int x = e.getX()/CSIZE; //GET THE X AND Y OF THE MOUSE CLICK IN RELATION TO THE SIZE OF THE GRID
            int y = e.getY()/CSIZE;
            Node current = map[x][y];
            switch(tool) {
                case 0: {   //START NODE
                    if(current.getType()!=2) {  //IF NOT WALL
                        if(startx > -1 && starty > -1) {    //IF START EXISTS SET IT TO EMPTY
                            map[startx][starty].setType(3);
                            map[startx][starty].setHops(-1);
                        }
                        current.setHops(0);
                        startx = x; //SET THE START X AND Y
                        starty = y;
                        current.setType(0); //SET THE NODE CLICKED TO BE START
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {//FINISH NODE
                    if(current.getType()!=2) {  //IF NOT WALL
                        if(finishx > -1 && finishy > -1)    //IF FINISH EXISTS SET IT TO EMPTY
                            map[finishx][finishy].setType(3);
                        finishx = x;    //SET THE FINISH X AND Y
                        finishy = y;
                        current.setType(1); //SET THE NODE CLICKED TO BE FINISH
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    if(current.getType() != 0 && current.getType() != 1)
                        current.setType(tool);
                    break;
            }
            Update();
        } catch(Exception z) {} //EXCEPTION HANDLER
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}

class Algorithm {      // ALGORITHM CLASS
    public void LeeAlg() {
        ArrayList<Node> priority = new ArrayList<Node>();    //CREATE A PRIORITY QUE
        priority.add(map[startx][starty]);    //ADD THE START TO THE QUE
        while (solving) {
            if (priority.size() <= 0) {    //IF THE QUE IS 0 THEN NO PATH CAN BE FOUND
                solving = false;
                break;
            }
            int hops = priority.get(0).getHops() + 1;    //INCREMENT THE HOPS VARIABLE
            ArrayList<Node> explored = exploreNeighbors(priority.get(0), hops);    //CREATE AN ARRAYLIST OF NODES THAT WERE EXPLORED
            if (explored.size() > 0) {
                priority.remove(0);    //REMOVE THE NODE FROM THE QUE
                priority.addAll(explored);    //ADD ALL THE NEW NODES TO THE QUE
                Update();
                delay();
            } else {    //IF NO NODES WERE EXPLORED THEN JUST REMOVE THE NODE FROM THE QUE
                priority.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> exploreNeighbors(Node current, int hops) {   //EXPLORE NEIGHBORS
        ArrayList<Node> explored = new ArrayList<Node>();   //LIST OF NODES THAT HAVE BEEN EXPLORED
        for(int a = -1; a <= 1; a++) {
            for(int b = -1; b <= 1; b++) {
                int xbound = current.getX()+a;
                int ybound = current.getY()+b;
                if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                    Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                    if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                        explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);    //EXPLORE THE NODE
                        explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return explored;
    }

    public void explore(Node current, int lastx, int lasty, int hops) { //EXPLORE A NODE
        if(current.getType()!=0 && current.getType() != 1)  //CHECK THAT THE NODE IS NOT THE START OR FINISH
            current.setType(4); //SET IT TO EXPLORED
        current.setLastNode(lastx, lasty);  //KEEP TRACK OF THE NODE THAT THIS NODE IS EXPLORED FROM
        current.setHops(hops);  //SET THE HOPS FROM THE START
        checks++;
        if(current.getType() == 1) {    //IF THE NODE IS THE FINISH THEN BACKTRACE TO GET THE PATH
            backtrace(current.getLastX(), current.getLastY(),hops);
        }
    }

    public void backtrace(int lx, int ly, int hops) {   //BACKTRACE
        length = hops;
        while(hops > 1) {   //BACKTRACE FROM THE END OF THE PATH TO THE START
            Node current = map[lx][ly];
            current.setType(5);
            lx = current.getLastX();
            ly = current.getLastY();
            hops--;
        }
        solving = false;
    }
}

class Node {

    // 0 = start, 1 = finish, 2 = wall, 3 = empty, 4 = checked, 5 = finalpath
    private int cellType = 0;
    private int hops;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int lastX;
    private int lastY;

    public Node(int type, int x, int y) {   //CONSTRUCTOR
        cellType = type;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        hops = -1;
    }

    public int getX() {return x;}       //GET METHODS
    public int getY() {return y;}
    public int getLastX() {return lastX;}
    public int getLastY() {return lastY;}
    public int getType() {return cellType;}
    public int getHops() {return hops;}

    public void setType(int type) {cellType = type;}        //SET METHODS
    public void setLastNode(int x, int y) {lastX = x; lastY = y;}
    public void setHops(int hops) {this.hops = hops;}
    }
 }
```

That is, the shortest path on the map goes somewhere to the side, and should be in a straight line. What should be corrected in the code?

Comment: For Lee's algorithm, the two paths that you show are equally good. It only considers the number of steps. If you want to consider geometric length, you need to add some edge weights to the graph. Then, your algorithm will become [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Also, please try to reduce your code to the relevant part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that according to the algorithm the answer is gave is as good as a strait line. Both the weird diagonal path and the strait desired path take 4 steps to reach the goal so they are both equal. To fix this you should add a weight. Instead of always incrementing hops by 1, increment it by 1.4 (sqrt(2)) when you move on a diagonal. This way there is a weighting for moving on a diagonal and the desired strait path would be the fastest (as it is in the real world).